# How do I properly annotate overloaded Java methods?

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-core.typed

In working to annotate [clojang](https://github.com/oubiwann/clojang), I'm having some trouble with protocol methods that call overloaded Java methods. I've narrowed the problem down to the following minimal tricky case from [`'clojang.jinterface.otp.nodes`](https://github.com/oubiwann/clojang/blob/master/src/clojure/clojang/jinterface/otp/nodes.clj):

```clj
(ns clojang.jinterface.otp.nodes
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :as t :refer [ann ann-protocol]]
            [clojure.core.typed.utils :refer [defprotocol]])
  (:import [com.ericsson.otp.erlang OtpTransport]
           [java.net InetAddress])
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [defprotocol]))

(ann-protocol AbstractNodeObject
  create-transport
  (t/IFn [AbstractNodeObject InetAddress int -> (t/Nilable OtpTransport)]
         [AbstractNodeObject String int -> (t/Nilable OtpTransport)]))
(defprotocol AbstractNodeObject
  (create-transport [this addr port-num]
    "Create instance of ``OtpTransport``."))

(extend-type AbstractNode
  AbstractNodeObject
  (create-transport [this addr port-num]
    (.createTransport this addr port-num)))
```

Per the JInterface Javadocs, [`AbstractNode.createTransport`](http://oubiwann.github.io/clojang/current/erlang/java/com/ericsson/otp/erlang/AbstractNode.html#createTransport(java.net.InetAddress,%20int)) can take a `java.lang.String` or a `java.net.InetAddress` as `addr`. While I believe I've annotated this correctly in the `ann-protocol` form, `core.typed` complains about the implementation (on the last line in the example). I suspect I can somehow fix this using `t/inst`, but have yet to sort out the exact incantation.

I know I could add the type hint, `^String` or `^InetAddress` to the arglist (on the second to last line of the example) and remove the other clause from the corresponding `t/IFn` form above, but how can I tell `core.typed` that either type is viable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a brief discussion with Ambrose on IRC, the solution we've reached is to branch on `(string? addr)` as follows:

```clj
(create-transport [this addr port-num]
  (if (string? addr)
    (.createTransport this ^String addr port-num)
    (.createTransport this ^InetAddress addr port-num)))
```

and to replace the `IFn` annotation with:

```clj
[AbstractNodeObject (t/U String InetAddress) int -> (t/Nilable OtpTransport)]
```